Calculating the closed-form expectation of the absolute value difference of general gamma probability distribution
I am trying to calculate the difference between two general Gamma distributions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution); however, while also finding the absolute value of it:
Thus I have two random variables $X, Y \sim \Gamma\left(\frac{d_l}{\beta}, \frac{1}{\alpha^2}, \frac{\beta}{2},0 \right)$, where $d_l \in \mathbb{N}_+, \alpha>0, \beta > 0$. Which in tern returns the following PDF:
$$
f_x(x) =  \frac{\beta  \left(\frac{x}{\alpha ^2}\right)^{\frac{d_l}{2}-1} e^{-\left(\frac{x}{\alpha ^2}\right)^{\frac{\beta}{2}}}}{2 \alpha ^2 \Gamma
   \left(\frac{d_l}{\beta }\right)}
$$
(where the $\Gamma(x)$ in the PDF represents the Euler gamma function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
As such I want to find the following for which
$\mathbb{E}[|X - Y|]$
For which the PDF becomes:
\begin{align}
f_{x-y}(u) = \frac{\beta ^2 \alpha ^{-2 n}}{4 \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{\beta }\right)^2} \begin{cases}
       \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ x^{\frac{n}{2} - 1}  (x-u)^{\frac{n}{2} - 1} e^{-\left(\alpha ^{-\beta } \left((x-u)^{\frac{\beta}{2}}+x^{\frac{\beta}{2}}\right)\right)} \right] dx & u \ge 0\\
   \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ y^{\frac{n}{2} - 1}  (y + u)^{\frac{n}{2} - 1} e^{-\left(\alpha ^{-\beta } \left((y + u)^{\frac{\beta}{2}}+u^{\frac{\beta}{2}}\right)\right)} \right] dy &  u < 0
   \end{cases} 
\end{align}
Where (given that this is a symmetric function we get that we want to evaluate):
\begin{align}
f_{|x-y|}(u) = \frac{\beta ^2 \alpha ^{-2 n}}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{\beta }\right)^2}
       \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ x^{\frac{n}{2} - 1}  (x-u)^{\frac{n}{2} - 1} e^{-\left(\alpha ^{-\beta } \left((x-u)^{\frac{\beta}{2}}+x^{\frac{\beta}{2}}\right)\right)} \right] dx
\end{align}
Where the expectation is finally:
\begin{align}
         \mathbb{E}[f_{|x - y|}] &= \frac{\beta ^2 \alpha ^{-2 n}}{2 \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{\beta }\right)^2}
       \int_{-\infty}^{0} u \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[ x^{\frac{n}{2} - 1}  (x-u)^{\frac{n}{2} - 1} e^{-\left(\alpha ^{-\beta } \left((x-u)^{\frac{\beta}{2}}+x^{\frac{\beta}{2}}\right)\right)} \right] dx du
    \end{align}
However, I would like to know if there is a closed-form solution for the problem (when $\beta = 2$, there is a closed-form solution since this results in being a Laplace integral and thus becomes solvable). I am pretty sure this "closed-form" solution will be in terms of a general Hypergeometric function, which is fine for me.
I do not want a simulated or computational solution.
